# Bind checkbox element to an element inside a contentpresenter

Tags: wpf, xaml

i can bind a checkbox ischecked to another elemtn in xaml as like as

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=textEditor,Path=WordWrap}">
<TextEditor Grid.Row="1"
            Name="textEditor"
            FontFamily="Consolas"
            FontSize="10pt"
            SyntaxHighlighting="JavaScript">

    </TextEditor>
```

it works nice, but for some reason i want to create texteditor inside c# code intead and put it inside a contentpresenter, but after this the binding does not work as i expect.

```
 <ContentPresenter Name="CpTextEditor" Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding TextEditor}">

    </ContentPresenter>

TextEditor = new TextEditor()
                         {
                             Name = "TextEditor",
                             FontFamily = new FontFamily("Consolas"),
                             FontSize = 14,
                             ShowLineNumbers = true,
                             WordWrap = false,
                         };
```

is there any way to fix the problem?
thanks

Comment: Is your checkbox binding to the element named `textEditor` or `TextEditor`? Binding is case sensitive.

Comment: in second senario it is bind to TextEditor

Comment: Are you firing INotifyPropertyChanged when you new out the TextEditor?  Also what does TextEditor inherit from?

Comment: Check TextEditor property is public and does implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0):

I have whipped together a quick example of binding the content on a ContentPresenter:

In essense you need to make sure the DataContext is correctly setup for your ContentPresenter, and that the control is exposed as a property of the DataContext.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding AControl}" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

This is the class that I will use for the DataContext, it implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.aspx) to ensure the binding for a given property is kept up to date:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
class Class1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private TextBox aControl;
    public TextBox AControl
    {
        get
        {
            return aControl;
        }
        set
        {
            aControl = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AControl");
        }

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
}
```

And finally the code behind for my window in this example takes care of setting the DataContext for the Window (which in turn supplies context to the ContentPresenter):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var myObject = new Class1();

        DataContext = myObject;
        myObject.AControl = new TextBox();
        myObject.AControl.Text = "abcd";
    }
}
```

Notes:
I had a previous answer up that was not correct.
Also I don't have access or know where you have sourced the TextEditor control from (it is not a standard wpf control) but would expect that using it in that same way I have used the TextBox here will work.